# Python sqlite3 - How to reset the values of an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY id after deleting some rows

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Right now I'm working on a project with a database. When I delete some rows, I want it so the ID's are reset so there are no gaps between them. 
Here's an example of what I want.

Current database.

```
ID: 1 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 3 Reps: 3 Weight: 3.0
ID: 2 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 3 Reps: 3 Weight: 3.0
ID: 3 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 1 Reps: 2 Weight: 3.0
ID: 4 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 1 Reps: 2 Weight: 3.0
ID: 5 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 1 Reps: 2 Weight: 3.0
ID: 6 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 1 Reps: 2 Weight: 3.0
ID: 7 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 1 Reps: 1 Weight: 4.0
ID: 8 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 1 Reps: 1 Weight: 4.0
ID: 9 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 1 Reps: 1 Weight: 4.0
ID: 10 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 1 Reps: 1 Weight: 4.0
```

Deleting rows 3 through 7 would yield......

```
ID: 1 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 3 Reps: 3 Weight: 3.0
ID: 2 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 3 Reps: 3 Weight: 3.0
ID: 8 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 1 Reps: 1 Weight: 4.0
ID: 9 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 1 Reps: 1 Weight: 4.0
ID: 10 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 1 Reps: 1 Weight: 4.0
```

This is what I want it to be.....

```
ID: 1 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 3 Reps: 3 Weight: 3.0
ID: 2 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 3 Reps: 3 Weight: 3.0
ID: 3 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 1 Reps: 1 Weight: 4.0
ID: 4 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 1 Reps: 1 Weight: 4.0
ID: 5 Date: Date Exercise: Squat Sets: 1 Reps: 1 Weight: 4.0
```

Here is the function I currently have...

```
def delete_range(self):
        """
        Deletes a range of rows in the SQL events table. The range is determined by entries in the starting and ending
        DeleteRowEntry entries. 
        """
        starting_index = int(self.startingRowEntry.get())
        ending_index = int(self.endingRowEntry.get())

        conn = lite.connect('fit.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""DELETE  FROM events WHERE(id >= (?))
                                  AND (id <= (?))""",(starting_index,ending_index))
        cursor.execute("""DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = 'events'""")   
        conn.commit()
        conn.close
```

Here's the setup for the table I'm doing operations on.

```
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , date text, exercise_id int, sets int, reps int, weight real)''')
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this with MySQL when it is a question about SQLite?

Comment: I thought they were the same exact thing haha ( :( ), edited it.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If anything in other tables or outside the database refers to those ids, you **really** want them to be stable.

Comment: You'd have to update every row following the deleted range and subtract the range length from their id.

Comment: All's well that ends well, @user2980081

Comment: @MartijnPieters , I have a window in my program which allows a user to look at their entries just as above, type in a range and delete them if they so choose. I feel like it would look better if there weren't any gaps in the ID's, and the user knew confidently which entries were being deleted since they are all sequential. I hope my explanation is satisfactory... Other than that I really don't have any good reason to do it, is this reason not good enough? I can't picture using the ID numbers later on ,although this could definitely be wrong.

Comment: @user2980081: In that case, these ID numbers shouldn't be a key, and _definitely_ shouldn't be the primary key. A better solution would be to select the rows in whatever their appropriate order is, and just show the user the index of each row into the row set. That index (which can be passed to SQL in various ways, e.g., via `LIMIT`, but normally is only useful in your window's code) is inherently transient, so there's no problem with it changing each time.

Comment: @user2980081: you can always use sequential numbering *in your UI*; the row ids remain internal, you just map the UI ids to those.

Comment: @user2980081: Nowhere is it written that your database row ids must correspond to what you are showing in the UI. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd update all rows after the `ending_index` to have a new `id` based on the delta between `ending_index` and `starting_index`:

```
cursor.execute("""UPDATE events SET id=id - ? WHERE id > ?""", 
               ((ending_index - starting_index) + 1, ending_index))
```

Don't delete the `events` row from the `SQLITE_SEQUENCE` table either; rather, update it with the `MAX(id)` from `events` after the above `UPDATE`.

But you *normally* really don't want to do this; other tables and external systems would expect a `PRIMARY KEY` row id to remain stable.

If you are worried about users being confused by gaps in the event ids, then don't show those ids to the end-user. You can always number the visible rows in the GUI sequentially but still track the actual database ids separately.

Comment: Nice; this is my #2, written cleanly instead of explained badly. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a very bad idea—the whole point of keys is that they're a stable way to refer to records (in another take with a foreign key, or in an application, etc.).

But if you really want to, just iterate over the rows in ID order and set them to the "right" values, like this:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM events ORDER BY id')
inner_cursor = db.cursor()
for i, row in enumerate(cursor):
    inner.execute('UPDATE events SET id = ? WHERE id = ?', i, row[0])
```

You can optimize this in two ways:

1. Don't do it after every modification, but only after the last one in a batch.
2. If you do it after every modification, just modify the ones after `ending_index`, and use a single `UPDATE` to set each one to `id - gap`.

Comment: Thanks , after reading over yours and some other comments I won't go through with it, I thought it would be a good idea! I'm full of these bad ideas haha!